# This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct) -when making user manual page

Tags: flutter, dart

i would try to use intro_slider to make a user manual page inside the application. The user can view it after user login into the app.

Exception has occurred.

> FlutterError (This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer
> has a context (and should be considered defunct). Consider canceling
> any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to
> determine if the State is still active.)

This exception occur whenever i navigate each of the module using navigation bar after trying the code(manageRecipe.dart-ManageRecipe()) below to make user manual in the app. What wrong with the code?
**the manageRecipe user manual is place inside the profile.dart page- Profile()

manageRecipe.dart

```
import 'package:intro_slider/intro_slider.dart';

class ManageRecipe extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ManageRecipe> createState() => _ManageRecipeState();
}

class _ManageRecipeState extends State<ManageRecipe> {
  List<Slide> listSlides = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return IntroSlider(
      slides: listSlides,
      onDonePress: onPressedDone,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    listSlides.add(Slide(
      title: "Premier League",
      description: "English Premier League or EPL",
      pathImage: "assets/userManual/userManual_background.png",
      backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
    ));
    listSlides.add(Slide(
      title: "La Liga",
      description: "The Campeonato Nacional de Liga de Primera División",
      pathImage: "assets/userManual/userManual_background.png",
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
    ));
    listSlides.add(Slide(
      title: "Bundesliga",
      description: "Federal League",
      pathImage: "assets/userManual/userManual_background.png",
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
    ));
    listSlides.add(Slide(
      title: "Serie A",
      description: "Lega Nazionale Professionisti Serie A",
      pathImage: "assets/userManual/userManual_background.png",
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    ));
    listSlides.add(Slide(
      title: "Ligue 1",
      description: "Ligue 1 Conforama",
      pathImage: "assets/userManual/userManual_background.png",
      backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
    ));
  }

  onPressedDone() {}
}
```

navigationBar.dart

```
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/All%20Recipes/viewRecipe.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/OCR/OCR_Page.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Profile/Profile.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Recipes%20Collection/RecipeSearch.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Recipes%20Collection/recipe_collection_home.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/BottomNavigationBar.dart';
import 'BuyingList/buyingHome.dart';

class BottomNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNav({super.key});

  @override
  // _BottomNavState createState() => _BottomNavState();
  State<BottomNav> createState() => _BottomNavState();
}

class _BottomNavState extends State<BottomNav> {
  int _currentindex = 2;
  List pages = [
    RecipesViewPage(),
    RecipeCollectionHomePage(),
    OCRPage(),
    HomeBuying(),
    Profile()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: pages[_currentindex],
          bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
              style: TabStyle.reactCircle,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
              items: [
                TabItem(icon: Icons.menu_book_rounded, title: 'All Recipes'),
                TabItem(icon: Icons.folder_copy_rounded, title: 'Collection'),
                TabItem(icon: Icons.document_scanner_rounded, title: 'OCR'),
                TabItem(icon: Icons.checklist_outlined, title: 'Buying List'),
                TabItem(icon: Icons.perm_contact_cal, title: 'Profile'),
              ],
              initialActiveIndex: 2, //optional, default as 0
              onTap: (int i) {
                if (mounted) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentindex = i;
                  });
                }
              })),
    );
  }
}
```

[this exception shown whenever i navigate from one module to the other using the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJCRn.png)